# Modify Javascript Submit() Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Attempting to modify an existing program.

When a button is clicked, it calls an `OnClick` method that calls something like:

```
document.forms.submit()
```

I'd like to just use the same code but add in:

```
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'block';
```

That will essentially unhide a page overlay with a loading overlay.

Is there some place where this could be done to just add this to the processing?

Comment: Change that code to do what you want?

Comment: Yeah, just add another click event.

Answer (score 1):

No reason why you can't have multiple listeners for your click event. Why not just add another "universal" listener somewhere?

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('#overlay').show();
});
```

Just make sure this snippet runs on page load and you should be good I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Why not calling the `submit()` function through another function and add whatever you want:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.forms.submit();
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'block';
}
```

While calling `myFunction()` with the `onclick` method

Comment: display overlay should probably be before the submit, since the submit will trigger a page reload (most likely)

Comment: Because all of the coding of this application already has the "submit()" built into all of it.  So all of the code would have to be re-written - which is probably 100+ updates.

Comment: Good thing find/replace exists in most editors. Several have even expanded that to find/replace within folder.

Comment: Kevin B - I have already used --- grep -r "function submit" /path/ along with a few other finding options.  This submit() function appears to be an embedded javascript feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another method to click event of the submit and call the previous function from that after you show the overlay, if you don't want to edit/don't have access to the old javascript method

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myNewFunction()" value="Submit" />
```

Javascript

```
function myNewFunction() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display='block';
  oldFunction();
}
```

using jquery, you can bind a click event to submit, then use the previous function as below.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='submit']").on('click',function(e) {
    $(".overlay").show();
    oldFunction(); //unless it's already binded and will be called
   });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the responses - this is a 'workaround' and not fully the solution.   This would have been the last option for me to do if no one had an answer to modify the submit() function directly.

Comment: Well, given the lack of actual code click function, the options are limited. See the edit to answer.